# Create new array sorting multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 3 arrays and want to merge them into one array using the key

first array:

```
dataStringold = $(this).data("old_position");
```

result: `["addpr_0", "addpr_1", "addpr_2"]`

Second array:

```
 dataStringnew = $(this).data("new_position");
```

result: `["addpr_0", "addpr_2", "addpr_1"]`

Third array:

```
var values = [];
$('.destino').each(function(){
   values.push( $(this).val()); 
});
```

result: `["1", "27", "2"]`

and all what i need to get eack key of them and merge in new array like that:

```
["addpr_0","addpr_0","1"] ["addpr_1","addpr_2","27"] ["addpr_2","addpr_1","2"]
```

how can do it?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is using the function `Array.from` and get each element using the index from the handler.

```js
let arr = ["addpr_0", "addpr_1", "addpr_2"],
    arr2 = ["addpr_0", "addpr_2", "addpr_1"],
    arr3 = ["1", "27", "2"],
    result = Array.from({length: Math.max(arr.length, arr2.length, arr3.length)}, (_, i) => [arr[i], arr2[i], arr3[i]]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the size of all the array is same, the below code works

```
var result = ["addpr_0", "addpr_1", "addpr_2"];
var result2 =  ["addpr_0", "addpr_2", "addpr_1"];
var result3 =  ["1", "27", "2"];

var newResutl =[];
var i =0;
newResutl=result.map(function(item){
  var n = result.indexOf(item);
  return[item, result2[n], result3[n]];
});

console.log(newResutl);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go over the first array through `for in` and use the `index` to access each element.

```js
const arr1 = ["addpr_0", "addpr_1", "addpr_2"]
const arr2 = ["addpr_0", "addpr_2", "addpr_1"]
const arr3 = ["1", "27", "2"]
const result = []

for (let index in arr1)
  result.push([arr1[index], arr2[index], arr3[index]])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array for an arbitrary count of arrays for getting a transposed array.

```js
var array0 = ["addpr_0", "addpr_1", "addpr_2"],
    array1 = ["addpr_0", "addpr_2", "addpr_1"],
    array2 = ["1", "27", "2"],
    arrays = [array0, array1, array2],
    result = arrays.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => (r[i] || []).concat(v)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```